# Como redirecionar todo dns para um proxy local?

Tags: dns, centos, proxy

Gostaria de redirecionar todo o trafego que passa por um servidor DNS para um Proxy local ou seja na mesma maquina... exemplo: 10.0.0.10 (DNS) >>> Proxy Local >>> Internet

EX:Por exemplo, maquina com ip 10.0.0.11 > setar o dns (10.0.0.10) e todo o trafego do dns passar por um proxy da mesma maquina que o dns esta instalado, e a maquina 10.0.0.11 acessar o servidor proxy pelo dns da maquina 10.0.0.10

Tenho o sistema CentOS 7

Comment: Explique um pouco mais sobre o problema?

Comment: Por exemplo, maquina com ip 10.0.0.11 > setar o dns (10.0.0.10) e todo o trafego do dns passar por um proxy da mesma maquina que o dns esta instalado, e a maquina 10.0.0.11 acessar o servidor proxy pelo dns da maquina 10.0.0.10, não sei se isso é possível...

Comment: Seria basicamente acessar um proxy pelo dns... mas apenas setando o dns na maquina do cliente...

Comment: Editei seu titulo e incrementei isso na pergunta para o pessoal melhor lhe ajudar. Sempre lembre nas perguntas tentar por o máximo de detalhe, como esse exemplo que você citou. Faz uma enorme diferença. =)

Comment: Muito obrigado mestre...